# What kind of matrix is in Matlab: "W = ones(1:numEntries); "?

Tags: matlab, matrix

One simple question..

Let's suppose in Matlab we have a variable: numEntries = 8

I know "ones" is used to create "1's matrixes" but what's the result of the following?

```
W = ones(1:numEntries);
```

And,if possible,where I can find a good reference about matrixes in Matlab? I looked in official documentation but it is not so clear to me.

Thank you very much

Comment: The Matlab official tutorials, etc. are a very good place to start learning Matlab.  What aspects are you have trouble with?

Comment: For example the question above. Moreover I can't understand sintaxes like: [~,inputDim] = size(entradas);

Comment: @dragonmnl I'm glad you got an answer, but what's stopping you from *trying* these commands and inspecting the result? Octave is free if you are having MATLAB installation / licensing issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ones` creates a matrix of ones. `ones` works for any number of dimensions, however if you specify only one argument, you'll get a square matrix of ones of that size. Otherwise, you'll get a `N`-dimensional matrix of ones, `N` being the number of arguments you give to `ones`.

If `numEntries` is 8, `1:numEntries` creates a 1x8 vector `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`. This vector being given as input to `ones`, you'll get a 8-dimensional matrix of ones, in which the size of 1st dimension (vertical) is 1, the size of 2nd dimension (horizontal) is 2, the size of third dimension is 3, and so on, until the 8th dimension, that has size of 8.

```
numEntries = 8;

W = ones(1:numEntries);
```

% To check sizes of each dimension of `W`:

```
size(W)

ans =
1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
```

% To calculate the total number of elements in `W`:

```
prod(size(W))

ans =
    40320
```

% **Edit:** to get the number of elements in `W`, `numel(W)` is faster than `prod(size(W))` :

```
numel(W)

ans =
    40320
```

Comment: thank for the answer. I understand what it does.. but I'm a bit confused. For example: W = ones(1:3) .. what's the result?

Comment: Unless you are able to visualize more than 3 spatial dimensions, it doesn't help much think of spatial dimensions. Even for 3rd dimension there is no spatial directions in MATLAB as there is for 1st and 2nd dim., so it's up to you to decide the "direction". All you need to know is which dimension of matrix refers to which dimension you are storing, measuring or calculating. It may be helpful to try to create some matrices of equal size and concatenate them in 3rd or greater dimension by using `cat`. Check [last example of cat documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html)

Comment: instead of prod(size(W)), use numel(W)

Comment: @GuntherStruyf: You're right, `numel(W)` is faster than `prod(size(W))`. Answer edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

It's an N-D (`N`-dimensional) array where `N = numEntries`.

More specifically, it's a N-D array of size `1 x 2 x ... x N` filled with all ones.